# The phrases "has ... in " vs. "contains ... of" in Baby Rudin

Tags: general-topology, analysis, definition

Consider the following two statements. (Assume $E \subseteq K$.)

> $E$ has a limit point in $K$.

vs.

> $E$ contains a limit point of $K$.

What do they each mean and how are they different?

Comment: English.SE might be a better fit for this question.

Comment: @Veckt Funny, but I'm a native speaker and I don't think that the people at English.SE would have the mathematical background to elucidate the difference between them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first says that there exists an $x\in K$ such that $x$ is a limit point of $E$, whereas the second says that there is a limit point $x$ of $K$ that lies within $E$.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your answers. They each helped me equally, so I'm choosing Hayden's since (s)he has less points and it was given first.

Answer (score 7):

The first one means that there is a limit point of $E$, say $x$, where $x\in K$.

The second one means that there is a limit point of $K$, say $y$, where $y\in E$.